# Loading a specific image with JSSOR

Tags: javascript, jquery, jssor

I've been checking out the fantastic JSSOR script. However, there's one thing I haven't figured out yet. Because the specific layout I'd like to use, I prefer to keep the 'Thumbnails' seperate from the slider itself. This has to do with an already designed responsive layout.

So what I'd like to know is:

**How can I load a specific image within the JSSOR carousel by an onClick-event** (when clicking on an HTML element that's outside of the JSSOR slider)?
What script could I use to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//when a click event fires, call $PlayTo to switch to specified slide.
jssor_slider1.$PlayTo(slideIndex);    //slideIndex is index of slide, may be 1, 2 ...
```